# How do I prevent Linux kernel from responding to incoming TCP packets?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

For my application, I need to intercept certain TCP/IP packets and route them to a different device over a custom communications link (not Ethernet). I need all the TCP control packets and the full headers. I have figured out how to obtain these using a raw socket via `socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_IP));` This works well and allows me to attach filters to just see the TCP port I'm interested in.

However, Linux also sees these packets. By default, it sends a RST when it receives a packet to a TCP port number it doesn't know about. That's no good as I plan to send back a response myself later. If I open up a second "normal" socket on that same port using `socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);` and `listen()` on it, Linux then sends ACK to incoming TCP packets. Neither of these options is what I want. I want it to do *nothing* with these packets so I can handle everything myself. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

I would like to do the same thing. My reason is from a security perspective… I am wanting to construct a Tarpit application. I intent to forward TCP traffic from certain source IPs to the Tarpit. The Tarpit must receive the ACK. It will reply with a SYN/ACK of its own. I do not want the kernel to respond. Hence, a raw socket will not work (because the supplied TCP packets are teed), I need to also implement a Divert socket. That's about all I know so far… have not yet implemented.

Comment: Not an answer, should be a comment